# Using Xor to find a duplicate in an Array

Tags: javascript

I have this following code that I created, but I'm having an issue on how to call this into a console.log on my developers tools, in order to see my results. I'm new to js...

```
var num = [5,3,1,2,3,5,1];

let duplicateValue = (num) => {
    let countVal = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i< num.lenght; i++){
         countVal = countVal ^ num[i];}
  return countVal; }
```

console.log(duplicateValue); return undefined.....

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you declaring a const arrow function when there is no `this` to preserve? Why not write a normal `function duplicateValue(num) { ... }`?

Comment: duplicateValue is a function so you would need to do `console.log(duplicateValue(num))`. It's a bit confusing because you have a global and function parameter with the same name `num`. You also spelt `length` wrong as `lenght`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typo length (lenght) and did not call method in console log

```
var num = [5,3,1,2,3,5,1];

let duplicateValue = (num) => {
    let countVal = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i< num.length; i++){
         countVal = countVal ^ num[i];}
  return countVal; 
 }
console.log(duplicateValue(num));
```

```js
var num = [5,3,1,2,3,5,1];

let duplicateValue = (num) => {
    let countVal = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i< num.length; i++){
         countVal = countVal ^ num[i];}
  return countVal; 
 }
console.log(duplicateValue(num));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to console like this. You need to pass the array as argument.

```
console.log(duplicateValue([5,3,1,2,3,5,1]))
```

```js
var num = [5,3,1,2,3,5,1];

let duplicateValue = (num) => {
    let countVal = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i< num.lenght; i++){
         countVal = countVal ^ num[i];}
  return countVal;
}

console.log(duplicateValue([5,3,1,2,3,5,1]));
```